# Correcting TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

foreach how to fix the code below so that the center of the figure is at the origin (0,0)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] circle (2pt) node[right] {$(0,0)$};
\draw (-3,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[blue] (-3,-2) -- (3,4);
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x}{
        \draw[|-|] (\x,\y) -- ++(0,1);
    };
};
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x}{
        \draw[|-|] (-\x,-\y+1) -- ++(0,1);
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

how to minimize the code?
I minimize the code? See:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] circle (2pt) node[below right] {$(0,0)$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw (-3,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[blue] (-3,-2) -- (3,4);

\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x}{
        \draw[|-|] (\x,\y) -- ++(0,1);
        \draw[|-|] (-\x,-\y+1) -- ++(0,1);
    };
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change the individual coordinates, you can put the code within a `scope` and shift everything down 1cm as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] circle (2pt) node[right] {$(0,0)$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]% Everything within here is shifted down 1cm
\draw (-3,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[blue] (-3,-2) -- (3,4);
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x}{
        \draw[|-|] (\x,\y) -- ++(0,1);
    };
};
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x}{
        \draw[|-|] (-\x,-\y+1) -- ++(0,1);
    };
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you can adjust the y-coordinate of each point is 1 unit less.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution shifted the all those lines in the loops. Instead, I suggest to shift only the point which is labeled (0,0) as the origin. So, just change your origin code line to

```
\draw[fill=blue] (0,1) circle (2pt) node[below right] {$(0,0)$};
```

and you will get, with the rest of your code:

[image: shifted origin]

Answer (score 4):

#### Fixes:

- The `|-|` arrows have one disadvantages: The `|` part isn’t centered at the end of the line but touches it (as all arrows do). In a simple example like

  ```
  \draw[|-|] (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw[|-|] (1,0) -- (2,0);
  ```

  this becomes very obvious (line width set to `2pt`):

  [image]

  This could be solved with the `shorten >` and `shorten <` keys set to `-.5\pgflinewidth` …
- … but I want to draw the vertical lines in one draw using the `decorations.markings` library. I can set the start position `1cm+.5\pgflinewidth` and the end to `1`. The step is set to `1cm`.

  The `.5\pgflinewidth` is there for the same reason why I would have used the shorten keys in the previous fix. (The `\arrows` macro uses the same placement algorithms as the usual end-of-line arrows as can be seen in my answers to [TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74638/16595) and [Adding double arrows to the middle of a line with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85244/16595))

  Unfortunately, I can not set the end to `1+.5\pgflinewidth` or `<length of line>+.5\pgflinewidth`. This would represent a marking that is not even on the line itself.
- This is the reason I use the `-|` arrow after all, but with `shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth`, so that the middle of the `|` lies directly on the line end.
- The start of the line does not get a `|` arrow (with or without shortening) because we already have a horizontal line there.
- The new macro `\maxLineLength` holds (half of) the number of lines, the unit-less length of the longest lines.
- The whole picture has its center at `(0,0)` (the blue dot) and can be shifted and transformed in its entirety.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    |-|-|/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions {1cm+.5\pgflinewidth} and 1 step 1cm with {\arrow{|}},
        },
        postaction=decorate,
        -|,
        shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth,
    },
}
\newcommand*{\maxLineLength}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-\maxLineLength,0) -- (\maxLineLength,0);
\draw[blue] (-\maxLineLength,-\maxLineLength) -- (\maxLineLength,\maxLineLength);

\foreach \x in {1,...,\maxLineLength}{
    \foreach \sign in {+,-}
        \draw[|-|-|] (\sign\x,0) -- ++(0,\sign\x);
};
\fill[blue] circle (2pt) node[below right] {$(0,0)$};% uses (0,0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`\maxLineLength = 3`)

[image]

### Output (`\maxLineLength = 10`)

[image]