# TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tkz-graph

I have something like this:

```
\SetVertexNormal[Shape     = circle,
                 LineWidth = 2pt]
\SetUpEdge[lw    = 1.5pt,
           color = blue]
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{1}
  \Vertex[x=0 ,y=2]{2}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {straight}}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
  \Edge(1)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This creates a simple directed graph with two nodes (`1` and `2`) connected by a blue arrow. However, I would like to move the arrow to the center of the line (instead of leaving it at the tip) and would like to change its color to red. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [assume](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) you're using TikZ and [`tkz-graph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph) …

You can use the `decoration.markings` library to set a marking at the middle position.
To the human eye this does not look like the middle, though, because only the *tip of the arrow* is halfway between `(1)` and `(2)`.
But you can use arbitrary TikZ code in the `with {<code goes here>}` part.
I cloned the first solution and changed it so that it does draw a zero length arrow (without a line). *To me* it looks better than the first solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\SetVertexNormal[
        Shape = circle,
    LineWidth = 2pt
]
\SetUpEdge[
       lw = 1.5pt,
    color = blue
]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{1}
    \Vertex[x=0 ,y=2]{2}
    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {straight}}
    \tikzset{
        EdgeStyle/.style={
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}
            }
        }
    }
    \Edge(1)(2)
    \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{1}
    \Vertex[x=0 ,y=2]{2}

    \Vertex[x=1 ,y=0]{1}
    \Vertex[x=1 ,y=2]{2}
    \tikzset{
        EdgeStyle/.style={
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\draw[red,->] (0,0) (0,0);}
            }
        }
    }
    \Edge(1)(2)
    \Vertex[x=1 ,y=0]{1}
    \Vertex[x=1 ,y=2]{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Compiled example]

#### Closer look

[image: closer look at the arrow]

---

More solutions can be found:
[TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)

Comment: Oh and one more thing if you wouldn't mind: is there anyway to use a solid triangle for the red arrow tip in the center?

Comment: @A.R.S. Take a look at the PGF/TikZ manual (cmd: `texdoc --view pgfmanual`), specially the chapter "Arrow Tip Library". You are probably looking for `triangle 60`.