# Tikz: draw a vector pointing from one point to another

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two points:

```
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (13.2,-23.4);
```

I would like to draw a vector pointing from point A to point B. The vector starts from point A, its length is other specified, and its end is not at point B. See the figure below. Is there an automatic way to draw the arrow such that I need not to calculate the coordinate of the end of the arrow every time?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the end of the arrow? Are you interested in [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161) or [TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74638)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: since the arrow points from A to B, its direction is determined. The length of the vector (arrow) is other specified. Then the end of the arrow can be computed. I will have a look at the links you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Additional to `shorten`, you could be interested in the `calc` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,5);
\coordinate (B) at (1,2);
\tikzset{-|}
\draw [|-|,help lines] (A) -- (B);
\draw[black,very thick] (A) -- ($(B)!1cm!(A)$); % 1 cm before B
\draw[blue, thick] (A) -- ($(A)!.65!(B)$);      % 65 % on the path from A to B
\draw[green] (A) -- ($(B)!.45!(A)$);            % 45 % on the path from B to A (55% from A to B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks. But it has a problem that it can only specify the distance between the end of the arrow and point B. In order to satisfy the specified length of the vector, the distance between A and B need to be computed, right?

Comment: @Shiyu No, `($(A)!<length of vector>!(B)$)` should work, too. (Should have made a better example …)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `shorten >= <length>`:

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,4);

\draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (2pt) node [left] {A};
\draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (2pt) node [left] {B};

\draw [-latex, red, thick, shorten >= 1.00cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's interesting. But we need to calculate the distance between A and B. Denote the distance between A and B as d. The specified length of the vector is d_1. Then the shorten length is d-d_1, right? how to compute the distance d?

Comment: @Shiyu: Not sure I understand. If you already know `d_1` then you can use that without knowing the distance `d`. `d` can certainly be computed, but just not sure what you want to do with it.  Try changing the shorten amount to `0.00` and see what happens, and replace that with `d_1` length.

Comment: I have tried the code. And it seems the shorten amount only specify the distance between the end of the arrow and point B, but not the distance between the end of the arrow and point A. So if the latter distance need to be a specified value, we need compute d and then compute the shorten amount as d-d_1. Hope I am clear:)

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel's method solves my problem. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,black,scale=0.2] (A) at (1,2) {};
\node[circle,draw,black,scale=0.2] (B) at (3,4) {};

\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow[black,line width=1.5pt]{>}}}}](A)node[below]{A}--(B)node[above]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: One important feature of this solution is that it doesn't double-draw the line from A to the arrow.  Namely, if the line from A to B is already drawn, this does not add an extra line on top.  If the line from A to B is not to be drawn, this probably isn't the desired solution (but the question is not clear on this regard).