# Draw two circles with line connecting them as in attachment

Tags: tikz-pgf

Would you please help me in drawing two circles with a line (middle arrow) connecting them.

O-->--O

Sorry I could not post the image.

*Edit******
Thank you so much.

Can you help me more? Here is my code. I need to draw that mid-arrowed line between the dot-filled circles.

Thank you

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dotted] (0,1) -- (0,10);
\draw [dotted] (1.5,1.3) -- (1.5,10);
\draw [dotted] (3.0,1.3) -- (3.0,10);
\draw [dotted] (4.5,1.3) -- (4.5,10);
\draw [dotted] (6.0,1.3) -- (6.0,10);
\draw [dotted] (7.5,1.3) -- (7.5,10);

% Lower Row
\filldraw[pattern=dots] (7.5,1) circle (0.2) ;
\filldraw[pattern=dots] (6.0,1) circle (0.2);
\filldraw[pattern=dots] (4.5,1) circle (0.2);
\draw (3.0,1) circle (0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi OOzypal and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Can you post a link to an image showing what you need? A user with sufficient privileges will edit your question and insert it then. Plus it would be nice to post your code so far.

Comment: Does [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161) or [TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74638) help you in finding a solution for the arrow? How are the circles specified? The `arrows` library gives you `o-o`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modification of your posted code with the arrows added.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [dotted] (0,1) -- (0,10);
  \draw [dotted] (1.5,1.3) -- (1.5,10);
  \draw [dotted] (3.0,1.3) -- (3.0,10);
  \draw [dotted] (4.5,1.3) -- (4.5,10);
  \draw [dotted] (6.0,1.3) -- (6.0,10);
  \draw [dotted] (7.5,1.3) -- (7.5,10);

  % Lower Row
  \draw[pattern=dots] (7.5,1) node[circle,minimum size=0.4cm,draw,fill] (A) {};
  \draw[pattern=dots] (6.0,1) node[circle,minimum size=0.4cm,draw,fill] (B) {};
  \draw[pattern=dots] (4.5,1) node[circle,minimum size=0.4cm,draw,fill] (C) {};
  \draw (3.0,1) circle (0.2);

  % Arrows
  \draw[->] (B.east) -- ($(B.east)!0.5!(A.west)$);
  \draw ($(B.east)!0.5!(A.west)$) -- (A.west);
  \draw[->] (C.east) -- ($(C.east)!0.5!(B.west)$);
  \draw ($(C.east)!0.5!(B.west)$) -- (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The main change is to turn the circles in to nodes that are labelled.  We can then refer to anchor positions such as `A.west` for attaching the lines.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{circ/.style={circle, draw, fill=white},
  conn/.style={postaction=decorate, decoration={
    markings, mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{stealth}}}}}

\tikz\draw[conn] (0,0) node[circ]{} -- +(1,0) node[circ]{};
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: the description in the question sounds to me like a dynkin diagram.  if that's the case, the circles here are much larger than the usual in such diagrams, and/or the arrowhead much smaller.

Comment: @barbara: Yes, then it is more difficult (not the size of the circles; that could just be a, say, `inner sep=.75ex`, but all the other dynkin diagram reqs, like double lines with large `angle` arrows etc.)