# Adding double arrows to the middle of a line with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am using `tkz-euclide` package and I am drawing a figure where I would like to put two arrows in the center of the line, exactly as seen in this figure:

[image]

Ideally, I may want to create a single arrow, two arrows, three arrows, etc. in the center of a line, so a generalized solution would be great.

Comment: Related: [TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74638/16595), [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/16595), the [`xymatrix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix) package

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. an example that has the lines already drawn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Notes

- The `\tkzMarkSegments[<opt>]{…}` macros offer the ability to `mark=` with `|`, `||`, `o`, `s`, etc.
  Refer to the [`tkz-euclide` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf) for more information (12.3 “Marquer un segment `\tkzMarkSegment`” and 12.4 “Marquer des segments `\tkzMarkSegments`”).
- I haven’t fount a way to be able to use, say, `mark=>`, which is the reason I provide the
- `arrowMe` style.
- `thick` is only one of many ways to make a arrow head bigger, this isn't the best, for further reference, take a look at

  - chapter 23 “Arrow Tip Library” of the [Ti*k* Z manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), and
  - [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/16595)
- Double arrows are provided by the universal `>` arrow or with the `\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble` macro.
- Triple arrow can be declared with `\pgfarrowsdeclaretriple` macro.
- Quadruple arrow can be declared with doubling the double arrow tip.
  With the example given you can see that the *end* of the arrow’s tip is actually at the specified position (here `pos=.5`) and not the *middle* of the arrow, which is the reason I prefer to use the method I described in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74646/16595), but the explained `decoration` doesn’t work so  good with `\tkz*Segment` so the fallback would be to explicitly `\draw` the line.
- See the related question where different ways of marking with an arrow are provided:

  - [TikZ-pgf directed graph: change arrow color and location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74638/16595)
  - [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\tikzset{
    arrowMe/.style={
        postaction=decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[thick]{#1}}
        }
    }
}
\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble{<<s}{>>s}{stealth}{stealth}%   double stealth
\pgfarrowsdeclaretriple{<<<s}{>>>s}{stealth}{stealth}% triple stealth
\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble{<<<<s}{>>>>s}{<<s}{>>s}%    quadruple stealth
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,4){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(7,4){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(3.5,2){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(6,2){BC}% only to show the quadruple arrow
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left=5pt](E)
    \tkzDrawSegments(B,D A,C)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](B,E D,E)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,E C,E)
    \tkzDrawSegments[arrowMe=stealth](A,B D,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[>=stealth,arrowMe=>>](D,A C,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[arrowMe=>>>>s](BC,E)% only to show the quadruple arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is very useful to me, however, I am still unsure how to add 3 arrows to a line

Comment: @James See my updated answer. For quintuple arrows (or others you can’t create with double and triple combination) there is `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine` which can be found in the PGF manual under 74.3 “Declaring a Derived Arrow Tip Kind”.