# How to mark a Segment with an arrow in Tkz euclid with the \tkzMarkSegment

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw a light beam on a prism. I've looked and I found that their are a couple of options, but none with an arrow. Any suggestions for doing this in tkz-euclide environment?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,intersections, decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetkzobj{all} no need with tkz-euclide v >3
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=7.5,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{2/1/A, 12/1/B, 7/7/C, 1/4.5/D, 12/6.5/E}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[size=2pt](A,B,C)
\tkzInterLL(D,E)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{S}
\tkzDrawSegments(D,S)
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](D,S)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you just want an arrow pointing in the direction of the light beam into the prism? So just an arrow head on what's already there?

Comment: No I want an arrow in the middle of the line, on the place of the |||

Comment: Right, then see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/adding-double-arrows-to-the-middle-of-a-line-with-tikz) which suggests that you can't do it just by writing `[mark=>>]` (which would be nice) but you have to create a custom style.

Comment: Thanks for this link, so it is not possible to adapt the option of the mark with the \tkzMarkSegment?

Comment: You could create a dummy point in the middle and draw the line there which would work as a hack but the answer linked by @Thruston is the more elegant.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, I prefer  the elegant way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've combined the advice of the others and put all together. (I'm not sure if this is the good way of doing this in this forum?)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,intersections, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
arrowMe/.style={postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[thick]{#1}}
    } }}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=7.5,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{2/1/A, 12/1/B, 7/7/C, 1/4.5/D, 12/6.5/E}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=red!30](A,B,C)
\tkzInterLL(D,E)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{S}
\tkzDrawSegments(D,S)
\tkzDrawSegments[arrowMe=stealth](D,S)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's not quite you want (you didn't tell us where the arrow must be placed), but if you replace

```
\tkzDrawSegments(D,S)
```

by

```
\tkzDrawSegments[arrows=->](D,S)
```

you get an arrow at the end of the segment:

[image]

**Edit** As said in the comments, here is a way to put the arrow in the middle of the segment. (Using the `decorations.markings` marking library.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %euclide loads base
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,intersections, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
%\usetkzobj{all} % inutile avec une version >= 3.01
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=7.5,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{2/1/A, 12/1/B, 7/7/C, 1/4.5/D, 12/6.5/E}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[size=2pt](A,B,C);
\tkzInterLL(D,E)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{S}
\begin{scope}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate}](D,S)
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want arrow in the middle of the beam

Comment: Then the answer is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line. I will soon edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I thought it was possible without a lot of code. But my problem is solved now.